# How do I convert a PNG to PDF with only the default packages on 11.10?

Tags: printing, pdf

Openning a png file in ubuntu, I can see the menu item for 'print to file'. How can I do the same on shell? PS: I prefer installing no extra package, due to lack of root access.

EDIT: the operating system is ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 176):

`convert xyz.png xyz.pdf` should do the trick.

See `man convert` for more options.

---

As mentioned in a comment below, if you get a security error, you may need to edit the security policy file. For additional details see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion

Comment: +1 - additionally you can use wildcards: convert *.png file.pdf

Comment: does this require extra packages?

Comment: Yes it requires the ImageMagick package, although it was there by default on my Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Also there by default on lubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Be careful if you use wildcards, files might not appear in the desired order, especially if filenames contain numbers (for example, a file named `17.png` will precede a file named `2.png`). To preview the order in which they will be merged into the pdf file, you can use the command `echo *.png`.

Comment: If you're using more recent versions of Ubuntu, you probably need to make this security exception: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081895/trouble-with-batch-conversion-of-png-to-pdf-using-convert
PDF looks beautiful, original images are unharmed.

Comment: convert-im6.q16: not authorized `h1.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.

Comment: `attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF'`

Comment: @Cerin same issue and this anwser fixed it https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180170/5472004

Answer (score 33):

If you want to **convert multiple images**, e.g. png files, **into one single pdf** use convert with the specified pdf filename at the end

```
convert *.png mydoc.pdf
```

It will merge all png files into a sinlge mydoc.pdf file in a descendant order.

Comment: convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.

Comment: It seems more like a problem of a security policy of the environment you are working on. Sorry, I cannot say too much about that error.

Comment: [Batch conversion of png to pdf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081895/trouble-with-batch-conversion-of-png-to-pdf-using-convert) has details on the 'convert-im6.q16' issue.

Comment: Thank you for your link, artless noise, the accepted answer worked fine for me !

Answer (score 7):

In 18.04 LTS, open image using ImageViewer; then print to file as a PDF.

Comment: Does not look like a command line advice.

Answer (score 1):

If converting each PNG file to **separate PDF files** is necessary:

```
for file in *.png; do convert ${file} ${file:0:-4}.pdf; done
```

This command takes all PNG files in a directory and produces PDF files with the same name.

Comment: Is that Imagemagick's `convert` command? Might it be the case that your answer is valid only up to Imagemagick V6? V7 would need `magick convert`? See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1315605/1157519 (Ah o.k. this thread is full with `convert`... Then again, those are dated answers.)

Comment: Don't use `$(ls *.png)` for looping over files. It's vulnerable for whitespace and unnecessarily verbose. Just use `for file in *.png`, which is neither nor.