# Trouble with batch conversion of .png to .pdf using convert

Tags: pdf, convert, imagemagick, png

```
convert /home/bill/TempScan/*.png  myfile.pdf
```

gives error message:

```
convert-im6.q16: not authorized `myfile.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should remove the word batch from the title. Google directs to the duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127260/imagemagick-convert-not-allowed with common search terms.

Comment: See also [ImageMagick:convert-im6.q16: no images defined](https://askubuntu.com/q/1181762/238253)

Comment: If you convert a GIF to a JPG and face the error message, you have to remove the `-write` command. See details in the imagemagick forum at https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=36460

Answer (score 370, accepted):

`convert` is a powerful command line tool to convert graphics. Its support for PDF is provided by Ghostscript. Because of a significant [security hole in Ghostscript](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928/) prior to version 9.24, use of `convert` on PDF files has been blocked as a stopgap. The issue has been fixed since Ghostscript version 9.24. While Ghostscript versions are updated to secure versions in all supported Ubuntu versions (at this time from Ubuntu 16.04 onwards), the usage restriction may still be in place.

The policy file is `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`. You may edit that file as root user to change the policies.

**Eliminating all usage restrictions**

For desktop users not running a webserver, simply eliminating these restrictions might be good enough. To that aim, one may delete the file, but it is better practice to "move the file out" by renaming it. With this command, you are renaming the file. As a result, all policies are lifted, but you still can revert if needed:

`sudo mv /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xmlout`

To revert to the original situation, just rename back to the original name:

`sudo mv /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xmlout /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

Be well aware that moving the policy file out decreases system security.

**Eliminating only the restriction to combine into PDF**

For your specific case, gene_wood in a comment pointed to the posibility to selectively relax the policy for working with PDF files by commenting out one line:

`<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />`

Edit the file, and place comment marks around this line to disable this rule:

`<!-- <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" /> -->`

If you do not want to eliminate all security policies, this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks vanadium, I renamed the file as suggested and it worked a treat.

Comment: I went into the `policy.xml` file and found the line that was preventing me from combining `png` files into `pdf`s and commented it out. That line was `<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />` if you'd like to leave the other rules intact but allow working with `pdf`s.

Comment: @gene_wood, thank you: I added to the post because it provides more insight and options for users wanting to be more careful in eliminating restrictions.

Comment: Ok, this works in Ubuntu 18.04 with imagemagick 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.4. Thank you.

Comment: The second method worked for me, but the first didn't.

Comment: Am I the only one thinking enabling this "feature" by default is pretty stupid? Reminds me of the automatically turned on "magic quotes" in earlier versions of php..

Comment: @qwertz Apparently, they did that because of a vulnerability bug in Ghostscript, which now should be solved. So possibly, this restriction on convert (which uses Ghostscript for this) will not be set anymore in future Ubuntu versions.

Comment: one more link to this security issue https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/pdf-not-authorized.html  but in this article Author states that "PostScript defines a language with unfixable security problems."  and "On a server that allows untrusted users to upload data for processing, ImageMagick should have PostScript and PDF disabled" worth reading

Answer (score 102):

As [vanadium posted](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081907/790920), you have to change the ImageMagick policy.

```
sudo vim /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

and replace the line

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
```

with

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
```

If you only want to allow write, and not read, you can also erase the `read|` part in the line above.

---

BTW, for those who are interested about the ImageMagick vulnerability, here are 2 informational links:

- https://www.enisa.europa.eu/publications/info-notes/what2019s-behind-imagemagick-vulnerability
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122328/how-to-prevent-the-latest-imagemagick-vulnerability

Comment: Short and straight to the point. Great answer.

Answer (score 25):

Rather than re-loosening ImageMagick's security restrictions, I'd just use [img2pdf](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf).

It's specifically designed for this kind of use-case.

> You should use img2pdf if your priorities are (in this order):
>
> - **always lossless:** the image embedded in the PDF will always have the exact same color information for every pixel as the input
> - **small:** if possible, the difference in filesize between the input image and the output PDF will only be the overhead of the PDF container itself
> - **fast:** if possible, the input image is just pasted into the PDF document as-is without any CPU hungry re-encoding of the pixel data
>
> Conventional conversion software (like ImageMagick) would either:
>
> 1. not be lossless because lossy re-encoding to JPEG
> 2. not be small because using wasteful flate encoding of raw pixel data
> 3. not be fast because input data gets re-encoded
>
> Another advantage of not having to re-encode the input (in most common situations) is, that img2pdf is able to handle much larger input than other software, because the raw pixel data never has to be loaded into memory.

This should be the equivalent command:

```sh
img2pdf --out myfile.pdf /home/bill/TempScan/*.png
```

If, for some reason, you can't do that (eg. can't install new packages), another potential avenue for lossless conversion would be to `convert` your images into a multi-page TIFF file and then use `tiff2pdf` from the libtiff tools.

Comment: +1 for good workarounds to avoid ImageMagick's security restrictions :-)

Answer (score 9):

Solution of abu_bua's solution really worked well for me. For convenience here in one command line with `sed`:

```
sudo sed -i 's/rights="none" pattern="PDF"/rights="read|write" pattern="PDF"/g' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an even more convenient way that automatically gets the location(s) of the policy.xml file(s) and performs the search/replace on them all:

```
for file in `convert -list policy | grep "Path:" | grep -v built | sed 's/Path: \(.*\)/\1/g'`; do sed -i 's/domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF"/domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF"/g' $file; done
```