# convert gimp mng to pdf no longer works

Tags: pdf, gimp

For over 4 years, I have been successfully using the Askubuntu method:

How can I export a PDF from GIMP with each layer on a new page

on LTS 14.04 to export an mng file and then convert to pdf.  However, as of
sometime between Sep. 19 and Oct. 26, the convert part no longer work and
produces an error message that I do not understand:

```
drrm@drrmlinux2:~/Downloads$ convert vt-02017_markup.mng vt-02017_markup.pdf

convert.im6: not authorized `vt-02017_markup.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1072.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with batch conversion of .png to .pdf using convert](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081895/trouble-with-batch-conversion-of-png-to-pdf-using-convert)

Comment: It is due to the implementation of security in convert. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081895/trouble-with-batch-conversion-of-png-to-pdf-using-convert/1081907#1081907. Marked this as a duplicate of that question

Answer (score 0):

I find an anser at the step 4 of this tutorial https://www.alanreed.org/2019/07/11/edit-and-export-multi-page-pdfs-with-gimp-2019/ 
It look be cause by a security setting, to disable it **rename the file /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml by /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xmlout**
for exemple.
Then you can convert your file.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks clovis, I'll try that the next time.  What I have been doing in the meantime is to use an on-line utility at https://convertio.co/

Comment: Doesn't work - Step 4 produces an error and

sudo mv /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xmlout

gives 

mv: cannot stat ‘/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml’: No such file or directory