# ImageMagick:convert-im6.q16: no images defined

Tags: 19.04, imagemagick, convert-command

According to this question, [How can I convert a series of images to a PDF from the command line on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955425/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-images-to-a-pdf-from-the-command-line-on-linux), ImageMagick can convert multiple images to a single PDF.

How could I reverse the operation and convert a PDF of several pages to multiple images?

I have tried the following command, but I got the errors shown:

```
$ convert test.pdf test-%02.png
convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/408.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `test-%02.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

`gs` was installed:

```
$ gs --version
9.26
```

Ubuntu version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco
```

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693820/12181862 has some tips.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Looks like some judicious editing of `/etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml` should sort out the issue: add `<policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="PDF" />` before `</policymap>`

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 @andrew.46

Comment: This error message is also fixed by the below answer `convert-im6.q16: not authorized filename.pdf @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1037.`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Interestingly enough ImageMagick under 19.04 (and other Ubuntu releases!) disables many ghostscript format types. This can be seen in this snippet from `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`:

```xml
<!-- disable ghostscript format types -->
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS" />
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPS" />
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" /> <------- Here!!
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="XPS" />
```

Of course I have added the arrow to catch your attention :). Modify this arrowed line to:

```xml
<policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="PDF" />
```

You can use your favorite text editor to accomplish this, using elevated privileges, or perhaps simply use the following `sed` *one-liner*:

```
sudo sed -i_bak \
's/rights="none" pattern="PDF"/rights="read | write" pattern="PDF"/' \
/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

And then all should be well, I have tested this comprehensively on my own 19.04 VM where the conversion you are after works *flawlessly*...

If you wish to change the settings back to *the default* the following one liner will restore the backup file created in the run with `sed`:

```
sudo mv /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml_bak /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

How cool is the command line!

Comment: what about Security issue with PostScript PDF described in https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/pdf-not-authorized.html ? Is  that any concern ?

Comment: @equivalent8 Fair call, note that the writers of this article stated: 'If we instead are talking about your desktop, then you might want to enable those data types for ImageMagick. '. These are changes I am happy to have on my own system...

Answer (score 21):

Another reason for getting that same error is that the source images are too wide, too tall or too heavy.

The `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` file controls what is acceptable as an image. Maximum width and height are set like this:

```
<policy domain="resource" name="width" value="10KP"/>
<policy domain="resource" name="height" value="10KP"/>
```

10KP stands for 10000 pixels. If your image is larger than that running `identify` will not show the image info in the terminal and the image is basically out of reach for Image Magick.

Other common properties that affect images being available or not are: `memory`, `map`, `area` and `disk`.

Here the document describing `policy.xml`: https://imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php

Answer (score 5):

+1 on all of the above.

Also note that my Docker container didn't have `gs` (Ghostscript) installed, so a very similar `convert-im6.q16: no images defined`  error message is thrown in that case.

Comment: Same here, after a `apt-get install ghostscript` in the container, (and the comment of the policy lines in policy.xml), everything worked.