# I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and when trying to use ImageMagick to convert pdf to jpeg format I get error. /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml: command not found

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, conversion, jpeg, policy

Thank you for looking at my situation.  I am running Ubuntu 22.04.  I wanted to convert a pdf file to a jpeg file format.  After typing

```
dr@Dell-1:~$ sudo /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

I get the following error

```
sudo /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml: command not found
```

I need to edit the policy [some thing I have never done being new to Linux] to allow for pdf files to be used with ImageMagick.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate? What duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081907/558158) gives you a detailed account of what you need to do. To overcome the restrictions, there are two possibilities:

1. Remove the policy file all together. Easy to do with a single `rm` (remove) command, but **not secure at all**. Thus not preferred.
2. Editing the policy file to only enable PDF operations. Indeed, prefer to take this approach.

To edit the file, you need to open it in a text editor with root (administrator) privileges. There are multiple ways to do that. To make editing as easy as possible, you may want to open the system file in your graphical text editor, `gedit` in the standard Ubuntu desktop:

```
env EDITOR=gedit sudoedit /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

If you can work with the standard terminal based editor `nano`, then the command simplifies to:

```
sudoedit /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

This opens the file in the standard terminal editor, `nano` on Ubuntu.

The command you attempted yourself just specifies `sudo`. This command should be followed by another command. `sudo` will then run that other command with elevated privileges (administrator or root privileges, required to change system files). will run a command following it, which will elevate the following command to root permissions. However, instead of providing a command, you provided the file name. Thus, `sudo` attempts to run that file as an executable, but that fails because it is not an executable. A way that would have worked, but which is less recommended for security, would be:

```
sudo nano /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

The previous commands that use `sudoedit` are preferred because more secure: the command will copy the system file to a temporary file that can be edited with a normal editor. When saving the file, the system file is updated with the content of the temporary file

Answer (score 0):

One word in the policy.xml needs to be edited in order to give permissions for ImageMagick to convert pdf files to images. ImageMagick also does batch image format conversion (see the example command at the end of this answer). If a pdf file contains multiple pages with images it is convenient to export the pages as single page PDF documents using the PDF Arranger app (`sudo apt install pdfarranger`) which also identifies each page of the output by including its original page number in its new file name.

1. Edit the policy.xml file /etc/ImageMagick-6/ in the terminal by running this command:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
   ```
2. Scroll down to the bottom of the file by pressing the down arrow key. Find the line that says `<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />`  replace `none` with `read|write` as shown in the below screenshot in the second to last line.

   [image]

   <sub>**Nano text editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
   <sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
   <sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

You can verify the results of editing the policy.xml file by running the following commands.

Convert a single pdf page to a .png image:

```
convert test.pdf test.png
```

Convert multiple pdf pages in the same directory to images:

```
mogrify -format png *.pdf
```

`mogrify` commands will overwrite any pdf files that have the exact same name if any such files exist in the current directory, so be careful.