# Where is the magick command of Imagemagick?

Tags: 20.04, imagemagick

This may be a simple question, however, I couldn't find a solution.

The ImageMagick contains a program named `magick` to [convert image formats from one to another](https://imagemagick.org/script/magick.php).

When I wrote `$ magick` into the console, I've got the following error.

```
Command 'magick' not found, did you mean:

  command 'magic' from deb magic (8.2.157+ds.1-1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

So, how to install the `magick` to Ubuntu 20.04.02 TLS?

Do I need to download and compile from the [source](https://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) or the name of the command in Ubuntu is just different from `magick` and it is already installed with the default ImagaMagic package?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I can confirm, no `magick` command on my Ubuntu 20.04 either.

However, try `convert`:

```
$ convert --help
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
Usage: convert-im6.q16 [options ...] file [ [options ...] file ...] [options ...] file
```

So I would try reproducing the examples in the documentation that you linked, but substituting `magick` with `convert`.

---

**Update:**

Thanks to [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver), I have quickly [learnt a lot about ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli) :)

The **ImageMagick version 6** command line API (shipped with Ubuntu 20.04 and earlier) consists of these commands:

> animate, compare, composite, conjure, **convert**, display, identify, import, mogrify, montage, stream

**ImageMagick version 7** will unify these commands under the `magick` command.

Be aware that from version 7 on, [such combos also become possible](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php):

```
magick convert rose.jpg -resize 50% rose.png
```

Comment: I see. Do you have any idea for the name change? It is better to create an alias instead of substituting.

Comment: No, I don't know why they are different in the documentation and in Ubuntu. But I would not be so fast with creating an alias. Such unexpected things often happen for a reason. We might not know the reason, but being quick to alter our systems (and dismissing the wisdom of the managers of our Ubuntu release) might set us up for unexpected surprises later on...

Comment: The name change goes the other way I think - `magick` is the *newer* API, available from ImageMagick 7 (whereas Ubuntu 20.04 uses ImageMagick 6). See for example [Porting Guide: Shell API or Command-line Interface](https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli)

Comment: Not all functionality, e.g. filename globbing, is supported in version 6's `convert`.