# How "Imagemagick" is on my system without my installation?

Tags: imagemagick

The system I use is "Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS". I did not install Imagemagick. but today after installing Latex its icon is on my applications list. does it relate to latex?! and why it's installed on my system without permission?

Comment: isn't it installed by default? see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315603/where-is-the-magick-command-of-imagemagick

Comment: Thanks, I checked it, that's right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Software packages often *require* other programs are installed, or *recommend* that they will work better with them.  These will then normally be automatically installed at the same time.

One way to find out why a program is installed is to ask on the command-line why.

```
aptitude why imagemagick
```

which will probably give an answer like:

```
i   PACKAGE Recommends imagemagick
```

which is the first **i**nstalled package it found that recommended or required it.

Comment: Thank you, dear Matin, It was clear.